# Do all countries members of ICAO share travel documents validity information?

Tags: borders, lost-documents

I want to have two passports, which is currently not allowed in the country where I am national.

I want to have one passport at home and another at some other place for redundancy.

Here is the (absolutely legal) plan:

1. get a new passport
2. wait a month
3. hide the passport so good that I forget where it is
4. declare passport lost
5. get a new one
6. suddenly remember where the first one is located

at that point I have two passports with almost ten years validity.

It is obvious that lost passport will immediately be invalidated in the national document database.

My question is - is there any standard / multilateral agreement to share revoked documents information among all ICAO members?

ICAO being organisation that publishes standard for travel documents ICAO 9303

Comment: If you declare a passport lost and it is not, then you are probably doing something illegal

Comment: This may depend on the country you are a citizen. Can you please edit that into the question?

Comment: What you're doing is called fraud. It's best not to commit fraud just to make travel a little more convenient.

Comment: [Interpol has one](https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Databases/Stolen-and-Lost-Travel-Documents-database)

Comment: @Relaxed That should be an answer.

Comment: Declaring that a passport is lost when you know very well that it is not, is **not** legal. You don’t give your citizenship but as random examples, the UK and New Zealand state that once you declare your passport or travel document lost or stolen, it cannot be used for travel. It will be canceled immediately and Interpol and border authorities will be advised. It is likely an offence against your country’s Passports Act/ regulations to knowingly or recklessly make a false statement to obtain another passport or travel document. To do so may result in a fine, imprisonment, or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this happens reasonably often (accidentally). Although having only one month between passport applications may raise some eyebrows.

Travelling with an invalid passport can lead to all kinds of inconveniences. If you make it onto the plane (e.g. if the airline has no access to a lost passport database end emigration just waves you through) and only get detected in your destination country, you might have to fly back. Or at least get into contact with your embassy.

Getting flagged as someone who deliberately uses invalid documents may lead to additional time-consuming checks everytime you need to prove your ID.

Fines for deliberately getting a second passport without turning in the old one are up to 5000 Euros where I live. We can actually get a second passport if we have a sufficient reason (e.g. want to travel to Iran but have an Israeli entry stamp in passport)

Answer (score 4):

There is no database "shared between all ICAO members". But [Interpol operates the Stolen and Lost Travel Documents Database (SLTD)](https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Databases/Stolen-and-Lost-Travel-Documents-database).

Implementation varies widely from country to country, both on the originating side (the country which issued the passport and subsequently declares it lost or stolen) and on the checking side (countries checking documents against the database), in many respects:

- some countries do one or the other, or both, others not all all
- some countries do it all the time, others more randomly
- some countries have very quick update processes and real-time checks, others use periodic batches

Travelling with a passport previously declared lost is bound to lead you into trouble, ranging from minor delays to expensive and very inconvenient refusals of entry, not to mention being held in custody for a little while. Not recommended.